# Is it possible to see ISS solar arrays with naked eye, from earth?

Tags: iss, visibility-of-spacecraft

I have a friend who swears that he saw the ISS and the arrays sticking out the sides of the bright light.  I'm thinking he has cataracts.  (We're both of that age.)

Is it possible he really did see the solar panels?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange! It turns out this has been asked before and answered, so your question may end up being marked as duplicate. Don't feel bad, this is just how stackexchange woks. You can [take the tour](https://space.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more. Please feel free to ask again, or just enjoy the other Q&A's here.